# Pipelined vs Low Latency implementation of cube of a number in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog

I was studying about FPGA design and then came across this terms `Throughput` and `Latency`. So the author provided an example of a highly pipelined implementation of finding the cube root of a number:

[image]

which apparently has the following logic diagram:

[image]

.Then the author has tried to reduce 'Latency' by writing the code like this:

[image]

which unrolls like this:

[image]

My question is to me both the implementations appear almost identical, so how are they different? I understand blocking and non-blocking assignment, but how are they causing a different logic diagram in this case? How is it decreasing the `latency` of the circuit in the second case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically speaking, you're correct they are identical. However, the first implementation is clocked (note the always `@(posedge clk)` statements vs the `@*` statements in the second), so it has a minimum three-cycle latency that is determined from the clock period. The second implementation is calculated completely asynchronously, so its latency is dependent only on the speed of your technology (how fast the multiplications and routing delays resolve).

What this example illustrates is that many digital functions can be implemented in a heavily pipelined manner or in one long logic path, or somewhere in between. Which you choose can depend on many factors. **The first implementation is less resource-efficient** as it uses many extra registers to store the pipelined values from cycle to cycle. **The second is more resource-efficient**, but if you plop it in a synchronous system running at a high clock frequency **it will be harder to close timing on**, because it fits so much logic into one cycle.

Notably, both implementations have equivalent *throughput*. Both can handle a calculation every clock cycle, it's just that the first implementation will supply the output three clock cycles after receiving the corresponding inputs.

Comment: So you are saying only the `always` statement makes the difference? What about the registers?why is it not there in the second implementation?

Comment: Yes, it comes down to the always statements. That's also why you see non-blocking statements in the first (always used for clocked assignments), and blocking in the second. You only see registers in the first because they are a "memory" device, which is needed in the clocked implementation to store values from cycle-to-cycle but is unnecessary in the unclocked implementation.

Comment: Nice..i did not know that..also how did you calculate 3 clock latency accurately..for me in first implementation the data arrives and after that the next rising edge will assign all values simultaneously..am i wrong?...but for the second implementation since its serial it should probably take 1 clock cycle + 2 multiplication cycles i guess?

Comment: @DuttaA I can see the three clock latency from a glance at the logic diagram, which shows three layers of registers. The second implementation doesn't do any clocking, so the latency would be predominantly the time for the multiplications, although in a real circuit you'd also have delays due to routing, buffers, etc.

Comment: What if we don't have such a diagram?

Comment: You can determine it through analysis. The key is to notice that the assignments occur on the posedge of the clock in a non-blocking manner. Then you just have the count the number of clocked assignments from input to output. In this case X -> X1/XPower1 (1 cycle), X1/Xpower1 -> X2/Xpower2 (2 cycles), and X2/Xpower2 -> Xpower (3 cycles). In this code sample it's organized quite clearly to show that, but it isn't always so.